# Objective C: Segue from one ViewController to another

Tags: objective-c, segue

Hello I was wondering if it's at all possible to 'reset' the view navigation and go to another view.

```
                    __ (2)[Objects List] -> (3)[Object Info] __
                   /                                           \
 (1)[Main Menu] __/                                             \__ (4)[Edit Protocol]
                  \                                             /
                   \____________ (5)[Protocol List] ___________/
```

All of these are their own ViewControllers and I would like to be able to navigate like this.

I want to go from [Edit Protocol] to [Protocol List] where the BACK button on [Protocol List] returns me to [Main Menu]

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks.

**Edit**

Added Numbers (1)(2)(3)(4)(5) to clarify what order I want this to happen in

Answer (score 0):

You should check `UINavigationController` and it's `popToRootViewControllerAnimated`: method when you want to go back to [Main menu].

I.e.

```
[mainMenu.navigationController pushViewController:objectList]; 
[objectList.navigationController pushViewController:editProtocol];
[objectList.navigationController pushViewController:protocolList];
```

And if user clicks Back button

```
[protocolList.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Could you clarify, I have imported protocolList.h into editProtocol.m and set it as a global value protocolList inside @interface editProtocol(). But [protocolList.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];  does nothing

Comment: Code above could be real code but it's more like pseudocode. What you need to do is check how UINavigationController work, especially pushViewController:animated: and popToRootViewControllerAnimated: methods. Without having knowledge of that you can't achieve your goal.